# jQuery + XML problems

Tags: jquery, xml

I've been trying to grab the Digg rss feed and parse its contents into a table as an intro to working with jQuery / XML. I took [this](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Easy_XML_Consumption_using_jQuery) webmonkey example and tried to customize it. Here is my js file:

```
    // File: readXML.js

// Start function when DOM has completely loaded 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // Open the students.xml file
    $.get("digg.com/rss/index.xml",{},function(xml){

        // Build an HTML string
        myHTMLOutput = '';
        myHTMLOutput += '<table width="98%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
        myHTMLOutput += '<th>Title</th><th>PubDate</th><th>Description</th><th>Link</th>';

        // Run the function for each student tag in the XML file
        $('item',xml).each(function(i) {
            diggTitle = $(this).find("title").text();
            diggDate = $(this).find("pubDate").text();
            diggDesc = $(this).find("description").text();
            diggLink = $(this).find("link").text();

            // Build row HTML data and store in string
            mydata = BuildDiggHTML(diggTitle,diggDate,diggDesc,diggLink);
            myHTMLOutput = myHTMLOutput + mydata;
        });
        myHTMLOutput += '</table>';

        // Update the DIV called Content Area with the HTML string
        $("#ContentArea").append(myHTMLOutput);
    });
});



 function BuildDiggHTML(diggTitle,diggDate,diggDesc,diggLink){


    // Build HTML string and return
    output = '';
    output += '<tr>';
    output += '<td>'+ diggTitle +'</td>';
    output += '<td>'+ diggDate +'</td>';
    output += '<td>'+ diggDesc +'</td>';
    output += '<td>'+ diggLink +'</td>';
    output += '</tr>';
    return output;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JQuery Easy XML Read Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="readXML.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="ContentArea"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, it doesn't work: it just prints the table headers without any of the data. (I checked the example and the code before I modified it worked just fine.) So, basically, where am I going wrong??

### EDIT

Here is the new code courtesy of andres (which still doesn't work!)

```
// File: readXML.js

// Start function when DOM has completely loaded 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // Open the students.xml file
    $.get("http://feeds.digg.com/digg/popular.rss",{},function(xml){

        // Build an HTML string

    myHTMLOutput = '<table width="98%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
    myHTMLOutput += '<thead><th>Title</th><th>PubDate</th><th>Description</th><th>Link</th></thead>';

  // Run the function for each student tag in the XML file
    myHTMLOutput += '<tbody>'
    $('item',xml).each(function(i) {


        // Build row HTML data and store in string
        myHTMLOutput += BuildDiggHTML(this);
    });
    myHTMLOutput += '</tbody></table>';

        // Update the DIV called Content Area with the HTML string
        $("#ContentArea").append(myHTMLOutput);
    });
});



 function BuildDiggHTML(el){

    // Build HTML string and return
    var output = '';

    output  = '<tr>';
    try { 
      output += '<td>'+ $(el).find("title").text() +'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+ $(el).find("pubDate").text() +'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+ $(el).find("description").text() +'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+ $(el).find("link").text() +'</td>';
    }catch(ex){
      output = '<td colspan="4">'+ex.description+'</td>';
    }        
    output += '</tr>';
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"digg.com/rss/index.xml"` redirects to `"http://feeds.digg.com/digg/popular.rss"`, try to change the URL.

JS + HTML:

```
...
// Build an HTML string

    myHTMLOutput = '<table width="98%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
    myHTMLOutput += '<thead><th>Title</th><th>PubDate</th><th>Description</th><th>Link</th></thead>';

    // Run the function for each student tag in the XML file
    myHTMLOutput += '<tbody>'
    $('item',xml).each(function(i) {
        // Build row HTML data and store in string
        myHTMLOutput += BuildDiggHTML(this);
    });
    myHTMLOutput += '</tbody></table>';
...


function BuildDiggHTML(el){

    // Build HTML string and return
    var output = '';

    output  = '<tr>';
    try { 
      output += '<td>'+ $(el).find("title").text() +'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+ $(el).find("pubDate").text() +'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+ $(el).find("description").text() +'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+ $(el).find("link").text() +'</td>';
    }catch(ex){
      output = '<td colspan="4">'+ex.description+'</td>';
    }        
    output += '</tr>';
    return output;
}
```

**EDIT:**

[jQuery Ajax Cross-Domain](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)

Comment: Hi - I've changed the code (which I've included in my original post), but I still have exactly the same results! Thanks for your reply; any more ideas though?

Comment: @Sean McRaghty Excuse me, but I made a mistake in the answer, you're doing cross-domain, this work in IE but will not work in other browsers. I pass a link in the answer for you to see a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.get('http://digg.com/rss/index.xml', {}, callback, 'xml');
```

callback is the function you've already written.

what you've missed is the `http://` part. I just added the 4th arg for a measure of safety, just in case the url does not return an appropriate MIME type.

Comment: Unfortunately replacing my $.get line with this breaks the thing completely - blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do a call to digg.com... that's a cross-domain request. You'll need to do the whole `jsonp` ([jQuery docs that mention it](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)) thing or just do this data gathering on your backend.

Also, just as a side note, you should get in the habit of doing:

```
var someContent = [];
...
someContent.push( "somestring" );
...
someContent.join('');
```

...instead of...

```
var someContent = '';
...
someContent += "somestring";
```

becuase you will find it much faster.